# Difficulty in understand the meaning of standard enthalpy of formation

Tags: mechanical-engineering, thermodynamics, heat-transfer, chemistry, heat

Standard enthalpy of formation is when one mole of compound is formed from its constituent elements.

Example : $H_2$(g) + $O_2$(g) —>$ H_2O$(L).

But we don’t say the same for $CaO + CO_2$ —> $CaCO_3$.

It is because $CaCO_3$ is not formed it’s constituent elements but from other compounds.

Q1: From other compounds , does it mean the most simplest state I.e it is not formed from Ca + $O_2$.

I want to confirm if that’s all the meaning of standard enthalpy of formation. I am getting a lot confused over it.

Q2 Also , for the equation above. We can never find standard enthalpy of formation but can find the standard enthalpy of reaction I.e addition of $\delta$H  of $CaO $ in solid state + $CO_2$  in gaseous state ?

Edit:
[image]

Comment: Which book has the examples you show? Are they from the same page, passage or chapter? Perhaps they are focusing on different things.

Comment: I’ll paste them on the Q.

Comment: So is your first example incorrect ? Either missing 0.5 as the result is incorrect as you are missing some oxygen.

Comment: @SolarMike Firs is correct. I’m asking for next one. That’s why I wrote but

Comment: It is incorrect, you have H2 + O2 to give H20 when the correct result would be H2O2 or even H2O + O. The4 second does balance but the first not.

Comment: @SolarMike Ok. Isn’t it really common to see H2+O2 gives H2O. In my textbook formulas , I have always seen it like this. The text took 1/2 mole of O2 and 1 mole of H2.

Comment: Your edit image has it correct - did you just miss it?

Comment: @SolarMike Yes. Ok. I think I got confused with which reaction you were pointing out to. I got it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer this definition for Hf: "The standard enthalpy of formation or standard heat of formation of a compound is the change of enthalpy during the formation of 1 mole of the substance from its constituent elements, with all substances in their standard states."

Simply put though heat of formation is a tool we use to quickly calculate heat of reaction for a compound.  If I know the heat of formation for each reactant and product I can use the formula below (Hess's Law) to calculate heat of reaction.

[image: heat of reaction]

Once the calculation is done we will know if the chemical reaction is going to be endothermic or exothermic and to what magnitude.

For your calcium carbonate example you wouldn't need to tell me the heat of reaction I could simply look up the heat of formation for $CaO, CO_2, CaCO_3$ and do the math in the formula above.

$CaO: Ca(s) + (1/2) O_2(g) --> CaO (s) Hf = -635.5 $KJ/mol

$CO_2: C(s) + O_2(g) --> CO_2(g)       Hf = -393.5 KJ/mol$

$CaCO_3:Ca(s)+C(s)+(3/2)O_2→CaCO_3(s)  Hf = -1207.0 KJ/mol$

**Given the reaction:**

$CaO(s) + CO_2(g) --> CaCO_3(s)$

$Heat of reaction = (-1207.0)-(-635.5-393.5) = -178 KJ/mol$

Comment: Ok. So , if Q says to find $\delta$H_f of the above reaction. Then , should it be -1207 or -178 ? Also , For formation of CO2. delta Hf = delta Hr ?

Comment: @SrijanM.T For question one: The heat of formation of CaCO3 is -1207 KJ/mol.  This is much more exothermic than the heat of reaction of CaCO3 from CO2 and CaO.  For question two: the heat of reaction is equal to the heat of formation as you have stated.